# How to restrict more than one session to the Website?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need not to allow user to open more than one tab or browser window of my website (index.html). So user must have no opportunity to open website in Explorer and Chrome at the same time. This must be done with pure JS or Nodejs. How it can be done?

Comment: You cannot reliably do that.

Comment: As @str said, you cannot reliably do it. Is there a technical reason why you want to do this?

Comment: You can only do that by never allowing any user to open your website - after you served them your content, they can always display it as often as they want.